# Have I not understood what "Uber" is?

Tags: united-states, vehicle, motor-vehicle

I just watched a random video where an Uber driver is stopped by the cops, and the cops eventually mention that "there's a lot of history on this vehicle", and mention that it makes sense that there is "history" on the vehicle because he is an Uber driver.

The driver then seems to imply that he's just driving the vehicle and that it isn't his.

But isn't the whole point of "Uber" that it's like "peer-to-peer taxi"? Isn't an Uber driver just some guy who has registered as a driver on an "app" and then he drives people from point A to point B, just like a traditional taxi, using his own car?

If it isn't his car, then whose is it?

If you need context, this is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-UQKkYWDUQ4

(The relevant part is a few minutes in, maybe 4:30.)

Comment: What is your question? What is Uber? Not a good question for Law SE. Or "can the police pull you over and ask you questions and search your car and what can legally say and do?"

Answer (score 4):

No, you have not misunderstood what "Uber" is. Uber allows private individuals to function as a private car service (much like a Taxi but not as regulated). Individuals must provide their own vehicles, or Uber partners with certain car rental companies to offer discounts to Uber drivers for using rented cars.

The video you posted, the individual was told that the officers wanted to run a dog around the car because the driver was refusing a voluntary search. The driver's concern was that if they found something, that they would arrest the driver saying that whatever they found was his. He was trying to say *"if you find something, you'll say I'm driving, it's my car, it's my contraband"*. This is a legitimate concern because police often hold the driver responsible for what they find on the passenger, or if the passenger were to stuff drugs (or whatever) in a place accessible to the driver, the driver could be charged.

He is not implying that it isn't "his car", he's trying to reason with the officers saying that if they do find something, they shouldn't attribute that to him automatically.

Comment: "Not as regulated" only in some jurisdictions.